# ActiveRecord select by partial condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have selection with few filters:

```
limit = 20
proposals = Proposal.from_user(@user).expired
proposals = proposals.where(status: params[:status] if params[:status]

render_json proposals.page(page).per(limit)
```

Which will generate db query with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.
What I am trying to do, is that in case of `.expired` it will return no more than 3 proposals that match this scope, so even if `.expired` has 20 proposals it will "add" only 3 proposals to `proposals` object.

I want to do that to display 3 last proposals(expired) in UI as "expired" with some actions (like subscribe to change)

Comment: is the `expired` scope a status too? If it's expired, do you still need the page?

Comment: Is not possible just to limit the first query with `proposals = Proposal.from_user(@user).expired.limit(3)`?

Comment: .expired is another scope with condition 'expired = true',

Comment: @Ben - good idea, i think ill build two queries, one normal with limit minus 3, another is expired with limit 3 ) Thanks